# How to access the comments generated during the nomination phase of the election?

Tags: support, election

During the nomination phase of the election, under each candidate's self-nomination form, there was a comment thread. I found those comments quite valuable in helping me decide whom to vote for.

I notice that since we entered the election phase, they're no longer visible on the main election page.

How can we see them?

Answer (score 2):

Those comments are still accessible through the "Nomination" tab of the election page.

Part way down on the right margin of the main text, there's a series of buttons for choosing which phase of the election to display:

[image]

Click the "Nomination" button to see comments from the nomination phase.

Comment: It's almost like you knew the answer before you wrote the question.

Comment: @NikeDattani I nearly did. I figured out the answer for myself while I was writing the question. I thought it would be useful to others too, so I added an answer using the button at the bottom of the "Ask a question" page.